# What is the difference between Memcache store() and add()?

Tags: php, memcached

I am wondering whats the difference between store() and add()? They seem very similar, however I notice add only adds an item if it doesn't exist. Does set set an item that already exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set will set it or reset it regardless whether it exists. Add will add it only if it doesn't exist. This would help if you have something that gets unset from the cached and then have 1,000 people make the same request and all trying to set it at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which api calls you are using, but if both these set some object with a key/value, the behavior should only differ when the key already exists. add will error, and store (or rather set) will replace.